# Attribute / Property names on custom elements

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm part of a team that develops a custom element library for a big customer (according to custom element spec v1). We've developed like 30 components so far, half of those being autonomous custom elements, the other half being customized built-ins.

We're currently in the phase of refactoring and unifying the API of those components. Almost all of these components have custom attributes / properties.

*With standard HTML elements* the convention is to use `data-`attributes which are reflected to and from the `dataset` of the element.

I'm aware of the fact that autonomous custom elements allow for free attribute / property naming as long as the name doesn't conflict with what `HTMLElement` already has.

The idea behind `data-` attributes as I understand is to make sure that no libary will begin implementing a custom attribute which might conflict with future versions of the HTML standard.

The same, though, should be valid for *property* names. Imagine the HTML standard would get a new universal attribute, let's abstractly call it *attr*. Of course that would also reflect to a same-name property on the HTMLElement prototype.

My questions are:

1. What is the suggested approach to evade future conflicts here? Is it to always only use `data-`-attributes for custom attribute implementations, and thus, avoid the conflict by working with the `dataset` instead of properties directly attached to the element?
2. If so, how would you then implement "boolean" data-attributes (where the attribute value doesn't matter, the state is implemented via absence/presence of that attribute)?
3. Is it possible to define own getters and setters for properties in the `dataset` of an element?

Please ask for clarification if anything is unclear. I tried to make the question as concise as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't worry about future-proofing my custom element attributes or properties against what may become a predefined attribute or property of `HTMLElement`. If the spec changes, then I will deal with it then. But to try to guess everything that might be used in the future is not possible nor worth my time.

I avoid using `data-` attributes for custom elements. The `dataset` values are only strings and do not convert well. For example if I do this:

`el.dataset.dog = {woof:10};`

then my tag get's an attribute like this: `data-dog="[object Object]"` and this `console.log(el.dataset.dog)` displays `"[object Object]"`. That defeats the purpose of many properties that may need to deal with objects.

I only create attributes for things that must be attributes. If I must allow the HTML to define default values or if I need to create a CSS attribute selector then I will create an attribute. But only under these two conditions.

I create properties (getter/setter) or functions for everything I need. It is easier to pass in data of any format into a property or function then it is to convert it into a string to pass in through an attribute.

*I have even taken over one or more of the existing HTMLElement properties and attributes. This is rare, but sometimes I need to do something with the value or I just don't want the default operation to happen. **Again, this is rare.***