# Is it good practice to create custom HTML attributes for custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, custom-element

When creating a custom element like `<input-field>`, should custom attributes still use the 'data-' prefix or would it be acceptable to simply use them as-is? Basically using `variation="abc"` vs `data-variation="abc"` for example.
And if it is allowed, would re-using existing attributes like `type` be allowed?

In addition, would it be bad practice to add custom properties to the element's object during creation like the following:

```js
class InputFieldElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.customProperty = {data: 123};
    }
}
customElements.define('input-field', InputFieldElement);
```

I'm aware that these methods work perfectly fine right now, but the question is more if it's actually intended behavior or if it's just a weird edge-case that could stop working at any moment.

Comment: Yes, data- attributes are still preferred

Comment: using ``data-`` is a team decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342835/attribute-property-names-on-custom-elements) more than 3 years ago.

You're free to choose almost any attribute name you like, except the universal attributes ( e.g. `id`, `class`, `title`). In some cases even re-using attribute names that exist on some elements (like e.g. `value`, `disabled`, etc.) makes total sense so component consumers can work with your elements as though they were existing HTML elements.

Remember this freedom only applies when using **autonomous custom elements** (`<foo-bar>`), ***not when extending built-ins (`<div is="foo-bar">`)!***

As to your second question, it's also totally okay to define/add properties in the constructor, but recent additions to the ES standard have added [public](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) and [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields):

```
class InputFieldElement extends HTMLElement {
    customProp = {data: 123}; // public class field
    #abc = "Hello"; // only accessible from within this class via this.#abc
}
```

Except the private member, this class does exactly the same your class did, effectively saving you the need for a `constructor`. Please note that `this` is not yet available when assigning values to private or public class fields, meaning you cannot setup computed properties this way.

Regarding your specific question asking for `type`, having that attribute usually is an indicator of bad class design (which is true for `HTMLInputElement` e.g., resulting in `text` inputs with a use- and meaningless `checked` property, and checkboxes that have a  `readOnly` property (which won't do anything either)), but cannot be changed any more due to web compat.

Comment: Thank you for the super in-depth answer and for the feedback about `type`! I mainly chose to combine it into one element to avoid code re-use but I will consider possibly changing it to avoid meaningless attributes.